# Display result of computation (javascript) in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to take two numbers from html and using javascript return sum of both but my num1 and num2 contains HTMLInputElement??

html:

```
<head>
        <script type ="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Value 1: <input type="text" id="tb1" name="tb1"><br/>
        Value 2: <input type="text" id="tb2" name="tb2"><br/>
        Result: <input type="text" id="tb3" name="tb3"><br/>
        <button onclick="validateForm()" Type="button" id="b1" name="b1">Go</button>
    </body>
```

javascript:

```
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.getElementById("tb1");
    var y = document.getElementById("tb2");
    if (x == null || x == "" || y == null || y == "")
    {
        alert("Value cannot be empty");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        //myAdd(x,y);
        alert(x + y);
        var num1 = parseFloat(x);
        var num2 = parseFloat(y);
        var total = num1 + num2;
        document.getElementById("tb3").innerHTML = total;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not parsing and adding `values` from those two inputs, but `objects` itself. Because of that your `if` statement block would `never run`, as you are comparing `object` to `null`.Also and you can't set `innerHTML` of an `input`,have to use `.value`.
**Check the snippet below**

```
parseFloat(x) //you must parseFloat(x.value),

document.getElementById("tb3").value = total; //you have to use .value instead of .innerHTML with input
```

```js
function validateForm() {
  var x = document.getElementById("tb1").value;
  var y = document.getElementById("tb2").value;
  if (x == null || x === "" || y == null || y === "") {
    alert("Value cannot be empty");
    return false;
  } else {
    //myAdd(x,y);

    var num1 = parseFloat(x);
    var num2 = parseFloat(y);
    var total = num1 + num2;
    document.getElementById("tb3").value = total;
  }
}
```

```html
Value 1:
<input type="text" id="tb1" name="tb1">
<br/>Value 2:
<input type="text" id="tb2" name="tb2">
<br/>Result:
<input type="text" id="tb3" name="tb3">
<br/>
<button onclick="validateForm()" Type="button" id="b1" name="b1">Go</button>
```